# employee information using angularjs and php

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm the beginner of angularjs and php.Here I try to do a simple task as employee information.But while i'm excute my code it gave the error like this Trying to get property of non-object in line 6 and line 7

@line 6=>$action = $postdata->action;
@line 6=>$data = $postdata->data;

please give the solution for me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add more of the code, where do you get `$postdata` from? What does it contain?

Comment: I got postdata from my app.js file. I just copy that part of code from app.js below                                                                                         var res = $http.post('pages/ngProcess.php', 
  {
   action : 'addEmployee',
   data : $scope.employeeData
  });
  res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   console.log("emp added");
   $scope.getEmployees();
  });
  res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   console.log("emp adding failed");
  });
 };

Comment: Thanks for ur replay @peter but still my code have some problem

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution should be something like this:

```
 $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
 $request = json_decode($postdata);
 $action = $request->action;
 $data = $request->data;
```